# Creating a large covariance matrix

Tags: r, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

I need to create ~110 covariance matrices of doubles size 19347 x 19347 then add them all together.

This in itself isn't very difficult and for smaller matrices the following code works fine.

```
covmat <- matrix(0, ncol=19347, nrow=19347)
files<-list.files("path/to/folder/")
for(name in files){
  text <- readLines(paste("path/to/folder/", name, sep=""),  n=19347, encoding="UTF-8")
   for(i in 1:19347){
    for(k in 1:19347){
      covmat[i, k]  <- covmat[i,k] + (as.numeric(text[i]) * as.numeric(text[k]))
    }
  }
}
```

To save memory I don't calculate each individual matrix but add them together as it loops through each file.

The problem is when I run it on the real data I need to use that it takes far too long. There isn't actually that much data but I think it is a CPU and memory intensive job. Thus running it for ~10 hours doesn't compute a result.

I have looked into trying to use Map Reduce (AWS EMR) but I've come to the conclusion that I don't believe this is a Map Reduce problem as it isn't a big data problem. However here is the code for my mapper and reducer I have been playing with if I have just been doing it wrong.

```
#Mapper
text <- readLines("stdin",  n=4, encoding="UTF-8")
covmat <- matrix(0, ncol=5, nrow=5)

for(i in 1:5){
  for(k in 1:5){
     covmat[i, k]  <- (as.numeric(text[i]) * as.numeric(text[k]))
  }
}

cat(covmat)

#Reducer
trimWhiteSpace <- function(line) gsub("(^ +)|( +$)", "", line)
splitIntoWords <- function(line) unlist(strsplit(line, "[[:space:]]+"))
final <- matrix(0, ncol=19347, nrow=19347)
## **** could wo with a single readLines or in blocks
con <- file("stdin", open = "r")
while (length(line <- readLines(con, n = 1, warn = FALSE)) > 0) {

    line <- trimWhiteSpace(line)
    words <- splitIntoWords(line)
    final <- final + matrix(as.numeric(words), ncol=19347, nrow=19347)
}
close(con)
cat(final)
```

Can anyone suggest how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Thanks to the great help from some of the commenters below I have revised the code so it is much more efficient.

```
files<-list.files("path/to/file")
covmat <- matrix(0, ncol=19347, nrow = 19347)
for(name in files){
   invec <- scan(paste("path/to/file", name, sep=""))
   covmat <- covmat + outer(invec,invec, "*")
}
```

Here is an example of a file I am trying to process.

```
1       0.00114582882882883
2      -0.00792611711711709
...                     ...
19346  -0.00089507207207207
19347  -0.00704709909909909
```

On running the program it still takes ~10mins per file. Does anyone have any advice on how this can be sped up?

I have 8gb of RAM and when the program runs R is only using 4.5GB of that and there is a small amount free.

I am running Mac OS X Snow Leopard and R 64bit v. 2.15

Comment: Something is wrong; I can't tell you what, but it shouldn't take 10+ hours to perform 44e9 multiplications and additions.  How long is it taking to process just one matrix?  Also, consider converting each vector from text to numeric *once*, rather than inside the loop.  Also, have you tried interchanging your loop nesting order?  I don't know if R is [row-major or column-major](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_major), but if you're unlucky, you'll be missing the cache on every update to `covmat`.

Comment: You should NOT be adding matrices element by element. Just use "+". It does not make sense to convert numeric to text and use `readLines`. If you know the dimensions of a file and that it is all numeric, you can just use `scan()` for input. There is a `write.matrix` function in pkg MASS that might save the overhead of storing. You might want to review your older questions. There is some hesitation in spending a lot of time when there is a track record of non-acceptance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I waited for an hour for one matrix but it didn't compute a result so I canceled the job.

Comment: @DWin Thanks for the reply. I will look into using scan() and using the "+" operator now.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: R is column major order. To test: `matrix(1:9,3)`

Comment: @DWin: Ok.  In that case, there's a good chance that the OP's loops are missing the L1/L2 caches every time.

Answer (score 4):

I have concerns about the logic in your loop. You are calculating a result which is essentially covmat + outer(in.vec).

```
   text <- c("1", "5", "8")
    for(i in 1:3){
     for(k in 1:3){
       covmat[i, k]  <-  (as.numeric(text[i]) * as.numeric(text[k]))
     }
   }
 covmat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    8
[2,]    5   25   40
[3,]    8   40   64
 outer(as.numeric(text),as.numeric(text), "*")
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    8
[2,]    5   25   40
[3,]    8   40   64
```

That doesn't make it wrong, just something that can be greatly simplified in R, and if that is what you really want, then this vectorized function can replace the entire inner two loops:

```
invec <- scan(paste("path/to/folder/", name, sep="")
covmat <- outer(invec,invec, "*")
```

You are also overwriting each of the results for successive files with your outermost loop, which was not what you said you wanted to do,  so you may need to decide what data structure to store those matrices in, the natural choice being a list:

```
matlist <- list()
files<-list.files("path/to/folder/")
    for(name in files){
         invec <- scan(paste("path/to/folder/", name, sep="")
         covmat <- outer(invec,invec, "*")
         matlist[[name]] <- covmat
                      }
```

Now 'matlist' should have as many matrices as there were files in that directory. You can access them by name or by order of entry. You can retrieve the names with:

```
names(matlist)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate your advice. I understand how this is much faster and more efficient. On processing 2 files it took 20mins which is much faster than my original code. To save me having to run the program for ~18 hours for the 110 files do have have any advice on how I can speed this up? Thanks.

Comment: You should edit your question above to include your current code. On my 4 year-old machine it took about 3 seconds to run: `mat <- outer(1:19347,1:19347, "*")` It did take a few more _fractional_seconds_ to do a similar problem with "double" numeric vectors. My guess is that you are swapping out to virtual memory. I do have a lot of RAM and that is a fairly large object.

Comment: @TrueWheel: You should probably add information about your OS, R version and installed RAM to address the concern about system resources.

Comment: This is theoretically great but won't each of those matrices be huge (1.5 gig)?  This list will be a very large amount of data.

Comment: That's correct @John. I suspect that even one or two such objects is going exceed the memory limits on many machines. We're just answering the limited question of "how to do X" but perhaps should also e asking whether the might be a better method. The goal hasn't really be described.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
covmat <- matrix(0, ncol=19347, nrow = 19347)
files <- paste("path/to/folder/", list.files("path/to/folder/"), sep = '')
for(name in files){
  vec <- scan(name,  nlines = 19347)
  mat <- outer(vec, vec, '*')
  covmat <- covmat + mat
}
```

I'm guessing but maybe you really want something like...

```
numFiles <- 110
mat <- matrix(0, ncol= numFiles, nrow = 19347)
files <- paste("path/to/folder/", list.files("path/to/folder/"), sep = '')
for(i in 1:numFiles){
  mat[i,] <- scan(files[i],  nlines = 19347)
}
covmat <- cov(mat)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I ran you first response on just one file and it didn't compute an answer in 20mins. I tried on sum dummy data of a 10x10 matrix and it works fine. Even if it did finish in 21mins for the 110 files it would take ~38 hours. Do you have any suggestions on how I can speed this up? Thanks.

Comment: It's that sapply command that takes a long time to compute.  It should still be much much faster than what you wrote.  Does my second version actually do what you really want?  That's a calculation of a covariance matrix of all of your files.

Comment: No, I have been playing around with cov but I am not 100% on what it calculates. I am trying to create covariance matrix using this equation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#Find_the_covariance_matrix and don't believe that is what it does.

Comment: OK, got rid of sapply but it wasn't the command at all, I hadn't considered that each of these matrices is very big.  That equation, I'm trying to grok it in that particular terminology on the site, not one I'd use.  But, you were right that you need to summarize as your go because doing it later is going to kill you memory wise.

Comment: You need to start with a toy example, maybe 10 lines of data in each sample and 5 files.  I'm guessing that if you get it right my second example will work.  It's clear from your initial question that you don't quite have down how to calculate what you need.  So, work with a toy until the answer comes out right.  What you need to do is going to be memory intensive at the end and you want to have everything just right.